# During Xml deserialization, matrix is returning null

Tags: c#, xml, deserialization

Got lots of trials to deserialize the following XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<map version="1.2" tiledversion="1.3.1" orientation="orthogonal" renderorder="right-down" compressionlevel="0" width="80" height="50" tilewidth="16" tileheight="16" infinite="0" nextlayerid="2" nextobjectid="1">
 <tileset firstgid="1" name="TilesetSA" tilewidth="16" tileheight="16" tilecount="4000" columns="80">
  <image source="../../TilesetSA.png" width="1280" height="800"/>
 </tileset>
 <layer id="1" name="Walls" width="80" height="50">
  <data encoding="csv">
3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,
3,81,81,81,81,81,81,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,
3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,
</data>
 </layer>
</map>
```

I don't have the opportunity to change the xml file, it must stay as is.
I Managed to retreive all attributes for "map", "tileset" and "image", but in the "layer" element, in can only retreive the attributes (id, name, width, height), the data element always remains null.

I created dedicated classes for "map", "tileset", "layer", "image" and "map".

Would anyone suggest me any code to solve this "null result" issue?

Comment: Can you post the code you wrote for deserializing the XML? Also, what's the class signature for Layer?

Answer (score 0):

Use following xml linq :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication159
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);
            string dataStr = (string)doc.Descendants("data").FirstOrDefault();

            int[][] results = dataStr.Split(new char[] {'\n'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Select(x => x.Split(new char[] {','}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Select(y => int.Parse(y)).ToArray()).ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i attachedd the codes i wrote: "code extract" is in the main program method, all other are the classes i created

Comment: Ii seems to me that the serializer class is not made for what i want to do, linq seems easier to handle, i'm putting a try to it right now.

Comment: Serialize will work if you create a GET/SET method in the data property which takes the inner text string and converts to an array.

Answer (score 0):

My code is as follow:

```
        public virtual void WriteSaveXmlData(string pPath, int pRoom, bool pNewGame, int pX, int pY)
    {
        //xml save serialization
        XmlSaving XmlGameSave = new XmlSaving();
        XmlGameSave.SaveRootPath = pPath;
        XmlGameSave.SavedCurrentRoom = pRoom;
        XmlGameSave.XmlIsNewGame = pNewGame;
        XmlGameSave.XHero = pX;
        XmlGameSave.YHero = pY;

        XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(XmlSaving));

        using (StreamWriter wr = new StreamWriter(GameRound.GameSaveRootPath + GameRound.SaveFileName))
        {
            xs.Serialize(wr, XmlGameSave);
        }
    }
    public virtual XmlSaving ReadSaveXmlData()
    {
        //xml save deserialization

        XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(XmlSaving));

        using (StreamReader rd = new StreamReader(GameRound.GameSaveRootPath + GameRound.SaveFileName))
        {
            XmlSaving XmlGameSave = xs.Deserialize(rd) as XmlSaving;

            return XmlGameSave;

        }

    }
    public virtual XmlMap ReadXmlMapData(string pPath, int RoomNumber)
    {

        XmlMap ReadTmxData = new XmlMap();
        XmlSerializer TmxXmlMap = new XmlSerializer(typeof(XmlMap));
        using (StreamReader rd = new StreamReader(pPath + @"P1\RoomMapSaphir0" + RoomNumber + ".tmx"))
        {
            ReadTmxData = TmxXmlMap.Deserialize(rd) as XmlMap;
            return ReadTmxData;
        }


    }
```